# computing len(str(sequence _of _numbers)) vs len('sequence_of_numbers')

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was computing the number of digits in 100,000!, which happens to be 456574. I did the factorial like this:

```
import math
math.factorial(100000)
```

I copy-pasted the output of that as the argument to `str()` and called `len()` (the number is huge, so it can't reasonably be pasted here):

```
print len(str(<copy-pasted output from math.factorial()>))
```

and it took some time to compute the number of digits! Then I pasted the same output between quotes:

```
print len('<same copy-pasted output>')
```

and this time the result was instantaneous.

Can anyone explain: Why is it that the `str()` method took longer than the `' '` method, when they both represent strings?

Comment: You're saying that you copy-pasted the output of `math.factorial(100000)` in two places, as the argument to `str()` and inside quotes `''`, and then called `len()` with each of those?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes that's what I am saying

Comment: The key point here is that conversion from `int` to `str` involves a base conversion (from base `2**15` or `2**30` depending on the platform, to base `10`). The base conversion algorithm that Python uses is fairly naive, and has quadratic running time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting a 456574 digit number to a string is not without cost; that is a *large* string, nearly half a million characters is almost half a megabyte of memory (on an OS X system, using Python 2.7):

```
>>> import math
>>> import sys
>>> p = math.factorial(100000)
>>> p_str = str(p)
>>> sys.getsizeof(p_str)  # memory footprint in bytes
456611
>>> 456611 / 1024.0 / 1024.0  # memory footprint in megabytes
0.4354581832885742
```

It takes a little while for Python to generate that string, and for your OS to allocate the required memory:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('str(p)', 'from __main__ import p', number=10)  # convert to a string, 10 times
25.308346033096313
```

So it takes 2.5 seconds, on average, to convert those digits to a string. If you actually copied and pasted *all* those digits (instead of using a variable like I did), then you need to add more time still, as Python has to parse the int literal, and produce an integer object first before conversion to a string can take place.

You can't compare that to a string of length 1 (`'p'`), which only takes a few bytes of memory (38 bytes on my system).

Comment: Can you tell me how does python generate that string. I thought python did it this way: just put `'` at starting and at the end of the input in `str()`

Comment: @johnsmith: no, you are passing in an *object* to the `str()` function. Here it is an instance of the `int` type. To convert that to a string, explicit steps have to be taken to figure out what characters have to be in that string. For an integer that means figuring out what characters (digits) should be used to represent the same value.

Comment: @johnsmith: on the other hand, using `'...'` syntax is called a *string literal*, and the Python compiler produces a `str` object from that syntax. You already provided all the characters for that string, so there is no conversion.

Comment: I tried to compute this `print len(str('<copy-pasted output of 100000!>'))'` this time I gave input to `str()` which is already a string and now also this is taking same time as before (when input was int) why so? now its no longer an int and now python no longer has to figure out what characters (digits) should be used to represent the same value.

Comment: @johnsmith: you are still trying to create a new 0.5 megabyte object, again that takes a little time. Both to parse the string literal and to create the copy.

Answer (score 1):

`print len('100000!')` will not actually compute the factorial, but just the length of the string `'100000!'` which is much faster than actually computing the factorial

Comment: This is, at best, a comment, and now outdated.

Comment: It was appropriate to the initial version of the question though, and while probably not very extensive, it did provide the reason why the program did not run as expected

Answer (score 0):

Taking 100000000000 as a proxy a very large number:

`print(len(str(100000000000)))` has to convert 100000000000, an `int` object to a `string` object before calculating its length.  Creating a very long string takes a long time, relatively speaking.

`print(len('100000000000'))` does not have to perform the string conversion because the quoted digits are a *string* *literal*,  i.e. already a `string` object, so it's quicker.

Answer (score 0):

`len(str(result))` first creates a string from the `result`, then computes it's length.

On the other hand, `len('result')` already has the string in the quotes, so you basically did the job of converting it to a string already before running the code.

I guess doing `str()` on large numbers takes a lot of time.